# How to make ">"TODAY()-7 not count future dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet with dates that are in the future as well as in the past and am trying to countifs all the dates that are within the last 7 days and NOT the dates in the future.
That is where ">"TODAY()-7 comes in.

I have been trying to use `=COUNTIFS(VALUES!A:A,">"&TODAY()-7,VALUES!B:B,"SCHEDULED")` but this counts the dates for the future as well.
Would I add something that counts the dats inbetween two other values?

[Here is a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GjbssbJ-YxmhNMir4cv_0BgzT0ZmbpX2poMm9gKTgaU/edit?usp=sharing) for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

The following formula will count the number of instances when column a is a in a range of including today and 7 days back `AND` column `B` corresponding value ="Scheduled". Note that the iferror will be necessary to account for a blank returned filter.

```
=if(ISERROR(FILTER(A:A,A:A<=today(),A:A>=Today()-7,B:B="SCHEDULED")),0,
counta(FILTER(A:A,A:A<=today(),A:A>=Today()-7,B:B="SCHEDULED")))
```

Since the above formula has a relative value (`today()`), one can test with this hardcoded formula to the below dataset:

```
=if(ISERROR(FILTER(A:A,A:A<=date(2022,12,15),A:A>=Today()-7,
B:B="SCHEDULED")),0,counta(FILTER(A:A,A:A<=date(2022,12,15),
A:A>=date(2022,12,15)-7,B:B="SCHEDULED")))
```

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 12/4/2022 | NOT |
| 12/5/2022 | SCHEDULED |
| 12/6/2022 | NOT |
| 12/7/2022 | SCHEDULED |
| 12/8/2022 | SCHEDULED |
| 12/9/2022 | NOT |
| 12/10/2022 | SCHEDULED |
| 12/11/2022 | NOT |

Comment: The. Best! Works like a charm.
Sorry I took so long, hopefully I didn't screw up your chances with the girl at the bar ;)

Comment: Actually, if the number is 0, then the formula counts it as 1. (See spreadsheet) I changed all options to "NOT" and the formula still counts 1?

A note for someone else, if you are using IMPORTRANGE and have column headers, use the first row that should have data in it.
Example: A header in row 1. Use IMPORTRANGE(url, Sheet1!A2:A)

Comment: @BenCamp. *"if the number is 0, then the formula counts it as 1"* not possible if you correctly established a filter that has a parameter of `A:A=Today()-7`. I checked out your spreadsheet and didn't see anything, but since zero is not within 7 days of today it wouldn't be included. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, you very quickly responded and I appreciate that :)
I guess I am confused, the result, even when there are no scheduled anywhere in the column, is 1. Is this supposed to happen based on the formula in the spreadsheet we are using?

Comment: Ahh... I see the issue. So if there are `zero` results from your FILTER, you get a result of `#N/A` (an error) which would still be `ONE` non-blank cell. In such a situation, you would want to create an error to catch the issue and return zero. THis should do it.... `=if(ISERROR(FILTER(A:A,A:A<=today(),A:A>=Today()-7,B:B="SCHEDULED")),0,counta(FILTER(A:A,A:A<=today(),A:A>=Today()-7,B:B="SCHEDULED")))` Good luck.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you for the help, this is great! I'll learn this better for next time I need it ;)